# Filter sharpening; a stub

Tags: filters, impulse-response

Filter sharpening is a technique to sharpen the magnitude response of a digital filter. Finding information online about it is problematic since almost all google hits will be about image sharpening (unsharp mask etc.), which is unrelated to filter sharpening.

A naive technique to sharpen a filter would be to cascade it with itself. This kind of works but there are ways to get steeper response for essentially the same amount of computation.

The simplest sharpening operation is to subtract the double application of a digital filter from twice the identity operation.

$H_{sharp} = 2 I - H ^ 2$

Pseudo code:

```
init_sharp2(params)
  return [ init_filter(params), init_filter(params) ] 

apply_sharp2(h, x)
  y1 = apply_filter(h[1], x)
  y2 = apply_filter(h[2], y1)
return 2 * x - y2; // 2I - H^2
```

A higher order sharpening operation is to subtract two times the triple application of a digital filter from thrice the identity operation.

$H_{sharp} = 3 I - 2 H ^ 3$

Pseudo code:

```
init_sharp3(params)
  return [ init_filter(params), init_filter(params), init_filter(params) ] 

apply_sharp3(h, x)
  y1 = apply_filter(h[1], x)
  y2 = apply_filter(h[2], y1)
  y3 = apply_filter(h[3], y2)
return 3 * x - 2 * y3; // 3I - 2 * H^3
```

Make sure you use separate instances of the filters when cascading!

References: (to be done once I have waded through all the unrelated google hits)

Comment: This is Q&A site: what is your specific question? For example you could ask "What are effective means of creating filters with steeper roll offs?", if that is what you mean.

Comment: Point well taken. I'm considering restructuring the question.